# Multiple indices logstash template

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, indexing, logstash

Since we are using different servers with different purposes, we configured FIlebeat to send the logs to one specific Index per server.
Beta Index:Beta
Test Index:Test
Build Index:Jenkins

All the filters are working properly but trying to get the .raw fields I believed the templates were not configured properly. Now I'm facing a hard time because it seems that everyone only use logstash- index

My output is:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["172.31.28.8:9200"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

Additionally, I installed the filebeat template, but again, it is waiting for "filebeat-" index and not for the one I have created.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to get not analysed fields or .raw when having indices different than logstash or filebeat. But I did got the solution yesterday while discovering the "Sense" app for Kibana. Although the geogash is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the feeling that it is because of your manage_template = false setting. Are you creating an index template of your own? If not, try allowing Elasticsearch to manage the template for you.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-manage_template

The .raw fields are not_anazlyed versions of the field. The default setting for a string mapping is analyzed (while the default setting for long, date, etc is not_analyzed). Strings by default have an analyzed main field and a not_analyzed (.raw) field.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/default-mapping.html

Comment: Yes, I did changed to true the manage_template. Additionally, I added edited versions of the filebeat template and added to elasticsearch with
`curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_template/beta' -d@/etc/filebeat/filebeat.template.json`
For easily create the templates, copy the filebeat template with the code before but before, you only have to modify the json file changing the template "filebeat-" to "beta-" (or however your index is called) and repeat the process the same for each index. Now I have the not_analyzed strings which I needed, I didn't get the extra .raw fields though

Comment: Did you try reloading your index field list in Kibana? (assuming you're viewing this in Kibana)

Comment: Yeah, I have to do that and also delete the previous indices. It didn't want to change to not analysed otherwise.